# Ensure in require runtime error when setting up ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error

I've been trying to set up ruby on rails.

I'd create a new project with

```
# rails new test
```

and I'd get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /usr/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:295:in `activate_bin_path'
    4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:295:in `synchronize'
    3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:230:in `finish_resolve'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:175:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:175:in `ensure in require': CRITICAL: RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.owned?: before false -> after true (RuntimeError)
```

I have been at for quite some time and I can't find a solution.

I've also made sure everything is updated with `# gem update`

And sorry if this is a simple problem, I am rather new to ruby on rails. I gather it might be a problem with the monitor package?

I'm running Linux with kernel 5.6.11-arch1-1 if that helps

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is the same problem or not, but I had a similar error (not in Rails) and this page is the first that appears in Google, so I am posting a solution if someone else happens to land here.

For me, what solved it was to run:

```
$ gem clean
```

Comment: Any one coming through: don't do this, it'll break a whole lot of your Ruby installation, especially if you're working on multiple different projects.

Comment: This operation is safe. If it uninstalled something you needed from another project, you should be able to `bundle install` in that project's directory. Although I agree it should not be used frequently, sometimes it is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Try reinstalling the Bundler by using

```
gem install bundler
```

Then you can run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. any other ideas?

Comment: do you  use rbenv or rvm ? (or other)

Comment: Worked for me. I use asdf.